# Euler lines are concurrent?

Tags: geometry

[image: I need to show that Euler lines are concurrent. I understand evrything until $GG_1/G_1 E=AI/ID$. How can we say that ?]

I need to show that Euler lines are concurrent. I understand evrything until $GG_1/G_1 E=AI/ID$. How can we say that ?

Answer (score 0):

In triangle $AO_1I$ line $GG_1$ is parallel to $AI$, so that $GG_1/AI=G_1O_1/IO_1$. In triangle $IO_1D$ line $EG_1$ is parallel to $DI$, so that $EG_1/DI=G_1O_1/IO_1$. It follows that $GG_1/AI=EG_1/DI$, Q.E.D.